# How can I retrieve a textfields text and store it as an integer 32 in core data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, ios5

I'm trying to get the textfields text, convert it to an int, and store it in a core data integer 32 attribute. I'm getting an error in the process:

```
Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSNumber' disallowed  with arc
```

Here is What I've tried:

```
// trying to convert
int intLength = [self.length.text intValue];

// trying to set the current garden attribute to the converted int
self.currentGarden.length = intLength;
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSNumber is an object and is not the same as int. Try creating a NSNumber using the constructor:

```
self.currentGarden.length = [NSNumber numberWithInt:intLength];
```